# How to supply Vcc to optocoupler?

Tags: opto-isolator

The purpose of an optocoupler is to provide isolation. How can it provide isolation if Vcc is connected at both sides as shown below ?

Also, I assume I connect the GND of VCC only at the right side, is that correct ?

[image]

So connect it like this ?:

[image]

Comment: The isolation will make sense only if both the GND and VCC are separate ones on two sides of the OC. In your circuit, if the `MCU` has a separate ground, you will get an open circuit on the LED.

Comment: can you please show a schematic of how to connect a 6-pin optocoupler?

Comment: Is this a rhetorical question? There are many ways to hook up opto-couplers. Normally with separate supplies and ground on both sides, but often with a common reference ground too. There are a ton of examples on the web and in app-notes.

Answer (score 3):

> The purpose of an optocoupler is to provide isolation. How can it
>   provide isolation if Vcc is connected at both sides as shown below ?

How you might want to connect the power rails or how many isolated power rails you want to use is up to you. The optocoupler provides isolation period. If you have a circuit that doesn't benefit from this feature because the power rails and grounds are common then that is a different matter but, the opto still provides isolation in its own right and as a device.

> Also, I assume I connect the GND of VCC only at the right side, is
>   that correct ?

In that non-isolated schematic GND MUST be the same net on both sides of the opto isolator. If you want isolation then use isolated (galvanically isolated) supplies. The circuit you show does not directly benefit from the isolation capabilities of the optocoupler.

Comment: why connect GND on both sides? Then the isolation has no meaning since return current will flow anyway...

Comment: Because as I said in my comment under the question, there won't be any closed circuit around the OC's LED.

Comment: This is a good answer, but could be improved by explaining what Galvanic Isolation is and how to implement it above. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galvanic_isolation

Comment: I just implemented it (6-dip package) without connecting any left  side signals to the right side so complete isolation as it should be. Thanks anyway for the help !

Comment: Isolation was a casualty the second you shared a common Vcc with both sides. With a common Vcc you have to common the grounds or it won't work. If it appears to work and you think you haven't connected the grounds then you will definitely find that they are connected.